# SQL Server Database migration from 2008 R2 to 2012 getting wrong decimal precisions

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssas, database-migration, data-warehouse

Migrated SQL Server database from 2008R2 to 2012 using backup and restore option

When I do aggregate sum on both the databases 2008 and 2012 decimal precision is coming different.
Because of this measure value in SSAS cube browser is calculated wrongly compared to 2008 R2 vs 2012

```
select SUM(rate) from [InfoDB]

2008R2 Result
3029520.583895


2012 Result
3029520.58389499
```

Please suggest any work around for this.

Comment: What is the datatype and the scale/percision of the rate column?

Comment: Its float data type Length 8 precision 53 scale is null